# Launch Fab File inside a python script

Tags: python, fabric

I have a `fab` script, it works fine. To start it, I execute:

```bsh
fab -H 192.168.xx.xx deployFiles deployConfiguration:'master',7
```

`deployFiles` and `deployConfiguration` are both functions in my `fabfile.py`. `'master'` and `7` are my parameters for `deployConfiguration`

I have another Python script and I want to launch, the previous `fab` command inside him.

How can I execute, my fabfile with these parameters from a Python script?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You just import them, and call them. Using either the settings context manager or setting the relevant settings on fabric.api.env

```
from fabric.context_managers import settings
from fabfile import deployFiles, deployConfiguration

with settings(host_string='user@192.168.xx.xx'):
    deployFiles()
    deployConfiguration('master', 7)
```

Comment: Wow, quick answer and she's perfect. Its works very fine! Thanks a lot