# Is there a simple method for executing command line statements, in windows, from within python?

Tags: python, mysql, windows, command-line

I've searched high and low for a simple explanation of how to execute command line, in windows, from within python.

The subprocess package seems to be the answer, but I do not appear to be sufficiently experienced to make head nor tail of it.

Some questions I have reviewed to no avail, through lack of windows focus, or through lack of examples and expected outputs. e.g. [Command line question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python)

Could someone, for example, explain how to achieve the following:

1. Create a filename in python (e.g. `"db_dump 2013-08-05.sql"`)
2. Dump a mysql database using the mysql command line utilities (e.g. `mysqldump --result-file="db_dump 2013-08-05.sql" --all-databases`)

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "create a filename". Usually one creates files.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
from subprocess import call
call('mysqldump --result-file="db_dump 2013-08-05.sql" --all-databases', shell=True)
```

Just remember, `shell=True` can be a security risk if you work with untrusted user supplied parameters. E.g. when you let an untrusted use specify the file name.

Comment: *`shell=True`* can be a security risk Yes it is and this begs a question - what did you use it for in this case? Also if you use `shell=True` then you should pass string not a list and vice versa - see http://bugs.python.org/issue7839

Comment: Is there something I need to do to get into the right directory? This still does not work for me.

Comment: Have a look at these commands: http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os-file-dir, especially `os.chdir()` and `os.getcwd()`.

Comment: @Piotr Dobrogost the question _strongly_ suggests the use case: Make periodic dump of a database.

Comment: I don't see how it relates to using `shell=True`.

Comment: `shell=True` is easier to try and debug. Since the question contained no reasons to assume using `shell=True` would be a security risk, I answered in the more straightforward manner.

Answer (score 0):

1. `fname = "db_dump%s.sql"%time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")` assuming thats what you mean
2. `os.system("mysqldump --result-file=\"%s\"
   --all-databases"%fname)`

Comment: Why did you choose to use `os.system` which is frowned upon and not `subprocess`?

Comment: he didnt seem like he needed output, nor concurency, and its not really any less secure than using shell=True (at least imho... I could be wrong)

Answer (score 0):

You could try Fabric, especially the "local()" command:

http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.7/api/core/operations.html?highlight=local#fabric.operations.local

in your python code you can use it like this

```
local('mysqldump ...')
```

Fabric is typically used from a shell (using the "fab" command and a fabfile.py containing the python code to execute). To include it in another python script check this (first answer):

[Launch Fab File inside a python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11764203/launch-fab-file-inside-a-python-script)

Regards,